# cv2 frame by frame capture

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am new to programming so I know things might be poorly optimized or I might be missing something obvious but I am trying to write a program with the open cv pip module that takes a video and  makes a jpg file of every frame in the video and am having trouble

```
import cv2
import os

path = input("File Path: ")

path1 = path.find('\\', 3)
path2 = path.find('\\', path1 + 1)
user = path[path1:path2]
user = user[1:]

file_name = input("Video Name With File Extension: ")

path = path.replace('\\', '/')

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(f'{path}/{file_name}')

framerate = vid.get(5)

total_frames = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

for x in range(total_frames):
    vid.set(1, x)
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(f"C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/res/frames", f'{x}.jpg'), frame)
       
success, image = vid.read()
```

When I run this code I don't get any errors in my terminal but I also don't get any output frames and if you are wondering the directory and video name I have given it I give it C:\Users\conor\Downloads\xian\templates\videos for the path and xian.mp4 as the video name and I don't know why I'm getting no output frames

Comment: I realise you may want to do this as a learning exercise, but wanted to make you aware that it can be done as a one-liner, with no coding, using `ffmpeg`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)  # 使用0、1、2选择摄像头


VIDEOFILEPATH = 'output.avi'
FPS = 30  # 帧率
# 获取相机帧的宽高，默认640×480
FRAME_WIDTH = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
FRAME_HEIGHT = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
print("WIDTH: ", FRAME_WIDTH, "HEIGHT: ",FRAME_HEIGHT)  

# 设置视频编码格式、创建视频流对象
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter(VIDEOFILEPATH, fourcc, FPS, (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT))

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # 一帧一帧获取画面
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    # frame = cv.flip(frame, 0)  # 上下翻转帧
    out.write(frame)  # 写入帧到文件中
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)  # 显示图像

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):  # 按q退出
        break

cap.release()  # 务必释放摄像头
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

https://gitee.com/anidea/opencv-python-learn/blob/master/video/camera.py#

Comment: Can you explain how your code solves OP's problem? Also, “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”